# Testdisk application does not list all the internal hard drives in MacOS Monterey

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, testdisk, macos-monterey

**Issue:** When running testdisk in macOS, it does not list the internal hard drives.

**Objective:**
I had a video file on the internal Hard drive that was deleted and mistakenly cleaned the trash, which I want to recover.

**Configuration already done:**

> System Preferences –> Privacy & Security –>
> Full Disk Access –> Enable for Terminal

**Screenshot of testdisk - not listing the hard drive**
[image]

Can someone please suggest on how to fix this issue to list out all the partitions of a HDD?

Comment: TestDisk can't read APFS

Comment: @Tetsujin, but it should detect the physical drive regardless what's on it.

Comment: Check if the drive is detected in disk management or whatever it's called on Mac. Disk Util? Check SMART. Note that author of TestDisk maintains a forum where you may get more authoritative answers.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen - it's not terribly important, as even if it gets past security it can't do anything. OP says Terminal has full disk access, but idk whether TestDisk is technically 'within Terminal'. I've never used it on Mac, because it can't really do much. Same for PhotoRec.

Comment: @Tetsujin, yes it seems that's the issue I never used a Mac in my life even ;)

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com//help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to provide an actual, researched, answer on here.

TestDisk is next to useless for Mac, as is PhotoRec.
They can't read APFS at all, so for any OS newer than High Sierra 10.12 it is totally pointless to install, unless the drive you are trying to recover from is FAT/ExFAT, which precludes any boot drive; and you shouldn't be using any FAT structure on Mac unless you absolutely need cross-platform portability. Even then it's better to use HFS & install a comparable reader utility on your other platform. FAT cannot store unix permissions or ACLs & will actually break some of the Mac's data structures such as Photos or iMovie libraries and Logic Pro Project files.

Installing software on the drive you are trying to recover is counter-productive. You may be overwriting the very data you are trying to recover.

Being already prepared by always having a known-good external boot source with rescue utilities is always better than panicking afterwards.
Having a tested, working backup solution is better still.

If you have none of the above, then copying the drive using `dd` to another disk first, before installing any new software, would be safer.

Answer (score 0):

The requirements to run Testdisk on MacOS are outlined in the Testdisk manual:

> 6.6 Running TestDisk, PhotoRec under macOS
> If you are not root, TestDisk (i.e. testdisk-7.1/testdisk) or PhotoRec will restart itself using sudo after confir-
> mation from your part.
> If your administrator account has no password (a blank password), you must give that user a password before using the
> sudo command:
> • Choose Apple menu > System Preferences and click Accounts.
> • Click Change Password.
> Terminal doesn’t show the password as you type. If you enter the wrong password or a blank password, the command
> isn’t executed and Terminal asks you to try again.
> If no disk is listed when running TestDisk or PhotoRec, select System Settings –> Privacy & Security –> Full Disk
> Access –> Enable for Terminal ( or TestDisk and PhotoRec themself)

Source:
https://www.cgsecurity.org/testdisk.pdf

That leaves you to verify that you run macOS with an existing root password.

Hint:
Do run Testdisk version 7.2-WIP (work in progress) instead of version 7.1.
As opposed to what the name 7.2-WIP suggests it is not a beta version but the result of a continuously improved version 7.1.

Comment: It still won't help it to read APFS ;)

Comment: The user does not specify the used file system. And if he wants to find lost partitions, he does not necessarily need the support of the file system therein.

Comment: The OP specified 'internal disk' & Monterey. That's almost sure money it's APFS. OP wants to recover a deleted file, not a lost partition. To do that, you first have to be able to read the disk. Chances are lower anyway, as they appear to have installed TestDisk to the same drive they're trying to recover from.

Comment: I only focussed on "Testdisk not running" as no file system was mentioned. I do not guess about the file system in question if the information remains hidden.

Comment: The info isn't really hidden, it's just not explicitly mentioned. It really doesn't have to be on Mac. Monterey dictates the system & data partitions are both APFS. Nothing else will work. Had the OP been talking about an external, then we'd have to ask [because manufacturers still insist in shipping them MBR/FAT which is useless on Mac, even though it technically works, but lots of people don't know that], but not for internal.

Comment: You are obviously familiar with Macs - I am not. Another reason to describe problems adequately for all to understand.

Comment: Actually, a good reason to not answer a question when you don't know the possible components of it.

Comment: @Tetsujin, You are right! With the Monterey macOS, Internal HDD format is APFS.  I have installed Testdisk to the same drive, I am trying to recover from, as I am trying to recover a deleted file.

Comment: Abh - TestDisk will not work for you. It can't read APFS. You shouldn't have installed anything to a drive you are trying to rescue data from - that act in itself may have overwritten the file you needed. Your best bet for a situation like this is to use Target Disk Mode & a second Mac, so you don't overwrite what you're trying to recover. You shouldn't use that Mac for anything else until you do, or every disk write reduces your chances of success.

Comment: Tetsujin, of course not. 90% of questions asked are lacking an adequate case description. But the users asking those questions are not even aware of the fact that they missed to report something. According to your logic you would rarely find my answers. Do want that? Nothing simpler than that. By the way, why didn't YOU answer the question?

Comment: It didn't need an answer really. I covered it in my very first comment. Everything after that has been people who don't understand Mac just confusing the issue by adding irrelevant comments & answers.